# Having problems viewing JavaFX FXML MenuBar

Tags: java, javafx, menuitem, menubar, fxml

I am having problems when viewing an FXML MenuBar. Below I posted an example. When I click on *File* the menu opens showing the only entry *Close*. Now when I move the mouse over *Close* the blue focus is flickering / flutter. The system I use is Ubuntu 13.10 and the Java version is jdk1.7.0_51. Is this a known Bug?

examle.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <MenuBar layoutX="111.0" layoutY="87.0">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It's been discussed here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1267071), but doesn't help much. <br>
Anyway, I can confirm this bug (Ubuntu 13.10, Java 7u51, intel graphics).